# Visual C++: 'streambuf' base class undefined

Tags: c++, header

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\strstream(19) : error C2504: 'streambuf' : base class undefined

I'm getting the above error and a 100 other compile errors. Why would this happen? In the editor if I right click the symbol `streambuf` and go to declaration it leads to the header file `c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\VC\include\iosfwd` and shows the declaration

```
typedef basic_streambuf <char, char_traits<char> > streambuf;
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old, but I found I had the same issue when trying to inherit from fstream.  The answer was to add before my class declaration:

```
using namespace std;
```